# ПЛЕНЕР - омонімія чи полісемія?

Tags: омоніми

Зацікавило слово **пленер**. Його значення в принципі зрозумілі - зафіксоване в словнику значення жанру живопису і незафіксоване, але вживане значення мистецького заходу, на якому ці пленери, власне і малюють. А от чи вважати це одним багатозначним словом, чи двома різними словами-омонімами спільного походнення? Таке моє питання.

Наводжу словникову статтю на перше значення:

> ПЛЕНЕ́Р, у, чол. У живописі — правдиве відтворення природного
>   освітлення, кольору, повітряного середовища.  ▲ На пленері — на
>   повітрі.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/plener)

І приклади контекстів, де значення інше:

[Перший міжнародний мистецький пленер “Salix”](http://botanicgarden.lnu.edu.ua/fotohalereya/pershyj-mizhnarodnyj-mystetskyj-plener-salix/)

[VII мистецький пленер](http://museum.oa.edu.ua/underground-gallery/exhibition/vii-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80.html)

[ЕКОЛОГО-МИСТЕЦЬКИЙ ПЛЕНЕР](http://www.dolesko.com/Ekologo-mistec-kij-plener.html)

Залежно від відповіді, доповнення словникової статті - а таке має статися під час випуску нових словників, **пленер** буде мати одну (полісемія) або дві статті (омонімія). Тому питання має водночас і теоретичне, і практичне значення

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взагалі щоб намалювати ПЛЕНЕР (чи можна взагалі так сказати?) художник йде "▲ на пленер" для того щоб "правдиво відтворити природне освітлення" (всі вирази з означення СУМ).

Це почали робити імпресіоністи на противагу академічному підходу коли робився етюд "на повітрі", а сама картина малювалася у студії за допомогою пам'яті і підготовлених етюдів. Ходити "на пленер" можна одному, у компанії друзів-художників (як це робили імресіоністи), або великим натовпом — відповідно для великої кількості людей потрібна організація всього процесу.

Власне всі приклади у СУМ як раз подані для ілюстрації "роботи на пленері":

> Він.. писав просто на полотні натуру на пленері (Мистецтво, 1, 1955, 40); Вчився [Ф. Г. Кричевський] у Рєпіна.., Рубо. Особливо тепло він згадував навчання в Рубо, який виховав у юнака смак до роботи на пленері (Вітчизна, 2, 1961, 171).

Судячи з оформлення статті у СУМ тут нема підстав вважати це омонімією (так само як сніданок може бути індивідуальним, або організованим для великої групи учнів/туристів і т.і.)

(У цій статті щодо підготовки художників маса прикладів вживання слова пленер і похідних слів: [Пленерна практика](http://kgpa.km.ua/node/191)).

Comment: Згода, але не зовсім. Якби все було так просто!) Ви розповіли про значення, які не зовсім відірвані від французьського виразу ("на свіжому повітрі"). Я б хотіла акцентувати на тому, що в моїх прикладах слово ПЛЕНЕР вже не є ані жанром живопису, ані практикою малярства, а вживається в значенні ФЕСТИВАЛЮ МИСТЕЦТВ, при чому далеко не тільки живопису, а й скульптури, народних промислів, навіть поезії, фотографії, відео. Останні три не з прикладів, але я особисто брала участь в таких заходах, хоч і не можу сказати, чи слушна думка була називати фестиваль поезії планером, то радше була гра словами.

Comment: Зате в моїх прикладах у питанні це назви заходів тих організацій, що викликають довіру, тобто вони стабільно проходять під цією назвою і вже призвичаєні. Питання в тому, що коли нове значення відходить досить далеко, воно має шанс стати омонімом. Пленер як 1) жанр, 2) зустріч малярів на свіжому повітрі 3) фестиваль на галявині/в приміщенні/де завгодно за участю будь-яких митців - чи достатньо далеко, чи ні від первісного ПЛАНЕРУ?

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна, «чи достатньо далеко» — мені здається, що ні. А Ви можете навести якісь приклади «коли нове значення відходить досить далеко і [таки…] стає омонімом»?

Comment: @Sasha колись ключ до дверей (пор. ключка «гак із довгим держаком») і журавлиний ключ були одна­кові за формою — і слово ключ було одне, але тепер, коли вже немає подібності між обома ключами, це слово пере­творилося на два слова з різним значенням: ключ1 «знаряд­дя для замикання замка» і ключ2 «ряд однорідних предметів, що рухаються один за одним, утворюючи кут» https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/omonimi/5-1-0-56

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна, ну, це дуже вже далекі значення; тобто дуже вже історично віддалене від нас те, що їх об'єднує. Мені здається, що оскільки «пленер» порівняно нещодавнього походження — то тут усе простіше.